# In a bandpass filter, when a square wave is applied into the input, why is the output a sine wave?

Tags: band-pass, step-response

So I have designed a second order resonant bandpass filter with a center frequency of 320 Hz and a peak gain of 10. It works perfectly fine, however, I am just wondering why when the input is a square wave, why is the output a sine wave. I am aware that the reason is likely because of step responses, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Are you aware of the Fourier series of a square wave?

Answer (score 5):

A good square wave will be composed of many harmonics at increasing multiples and decreasing amplitudes of the fundamental frequency. As you start to "filter" out the upper harmonics you begin lose the squareness of the wave until you eventually wind up with only the fundamental sine wave. The chart below shows the harmonics that make up a square wave.

In the chart the N is the frequency multiple and A is the amplitude. Note that starting from the bottom right wave shape (approximately square) the wave becomes increasingly distorted until you get back to the just the simple sine wave.

In most cases a good square wave will have many more harmonics that further square up the wave. A perfect square wave would ideally require an infinite number of harmonics.

[image]

Above image from:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Square-Wave-as-A-Summation-of-Sine-Wave-3_fig1_338041688